# How do I represent a B-tree as a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, database

What resources are available where I can learn how to represent a b-tree using a two-dimenstional array?  Searching on Google did not provide any fruitful results.

Comment: What would be the member of such an array?  Hard to imagine how such a representation would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the reasons why you might want to do this, because no one would recommend it, which explains why Google doesn't have much on the subject, the trick is to use indexes into the array in place of pointers.

Then you have one dimension of the array representing nodes in the tree, and the other dimension representing child nodes.

It's related to the problem you would solve if you had to write out a btree to disk, where the disk is essentially a one-dimensional array.

Comment: which method would you recommend then? promela doesnt support recursive types. please see my question

Comment: I recommended a method.  Read above.

Comment: "no one would recommend it"